# Cannot add a visualstudio.com Team Explorer Server in Xamarin Studio

Tags: tfs, xamarin-studio

Having trouble adding a Team Explorer server (visualstudio.com) in Xamarin Studio. I enter my credentials (Microsoft account) but nothing happens, and the server is not added in the list of servers. I am using [this addin](http://indomitable.github.io/monodevelop-tfs-addin/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to enable alternate credentials to be able to log into the server as per this [post](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2012-aug-27-vso). See the "Basic auth" section.